# SSL errors logging for non https site

Tags: php, ssl, https

I have http://example.com without https enabled.
I noticed some  links with https like https://example.com/sslsecured-content in internet to my site.
I track all traffic with PHP script in my pages. But since when https request comes, my page is not opened (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID) and the event is not logged.
How can I log https traffic errors?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't log it if you don't run a webserver listening on https. https goes to a different port (443). When a https-request comes to a webserver without https enabled, it will hit a closed port. The operating system will reply - and your php script will never be aware of the request.

Anyway, the solution today is to *always* use https. There's no good reason not to use TLS with a public-facing website. With Let's Encrypt, it's trivial to automate and it's free. So my suggestion would be to use https for ***everything***, and set up a redirect from http to https for your site.

[This howto fro DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) gives you information on configuring it. You may also ask a question on AskUbuntu on how to configure TLS on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you. But I can't use https - because of client requirements.